# The correct way to use `strcat()` when the destination does not have enough space?

Tags: c, string, strcat

`man strcat` says the following.

```
char *strcat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
```

> The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result.

What is the correct way to handle the situation when `s1` does not have enough space?

Comment: You use `strncat()`.

Comment: ^ note that `strncat` is often used incorrectly. The third parameter is the maximum number of characters to *read* from the source, excluding the null terminator.  It's not the dest buffer size, nor the dest buffer remaining size.

Answer (score 1):

If `s1` does not contain sufficient space to hold `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1`, trying to use `strcat(s1, s2)` has undefined behavior.

There's no internal checking in `strcat` for a buffer overflow of `s1`. If you overflow, you overflow. However, there are some platform-specific alternatives which if used correctly can reduce the risk of overflow. As a Windows developer I prefer `StringCchCat` and `StringCbCat` in [`<strsafe.h>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strsafe.h).

If you want to guarantee safety for `strcat`, you can wrap it yourself. Something like:

```
int safe_strcat(char *s1, char *s2, size_t s1_size)
{
    if (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1 > s1_size)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    strcat(s1, s2);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcat(s1, s2);` can lead to overflow so the precaution "The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result." is warranted.

Assume `s1` can hold `N` characters: `N-1` non-`'\0'` + the *null character*.

> The correct way to use `strcat()` when the destination does not have enough space?

When the concatenation may overflow, I see no application to use `strcat()`.  Instead use other functions.

---

To detect potential overflow:

1. Test `strlen(s1), strlen(s2)` prior to the call.

   ```
   size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
   assert(l1 < N); // This really should be true already.
   N -= l1;
   size_t l2 = strlen(s2);
   if (l1 >= N) Handle_TooBigSomehow();
   strcpy(s1 + l1, s2);
   ```
2. Use `strncat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n)`

Note that `n` here is **not** `N`: the size available to `s1`.

> The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and
>   characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. The initial character of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. A terminating null character is always appended to the result. C11  §7.23.3.2 2

```
    size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
    assert(l1 < N); // This really should be true already.
    strncat(s1, s2, N - 1 - l1);
    // or faster
    strncat(s1 + l1, s2, N - 1 - l1);
```

Unfortunately there is no  clear indication that there was insufficient space, yet at least there is no overflow and `s1` is null character terminated.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination buffer already holds a string of length M, and you want to add to it another string of length N, then that buffer has to be at least M + N + 1 bytes wide. If it is smaller, then you just cannot do this; it is impossible to add that material to the existing string. If you put the material there anyway, it will overrun the buffer, whereupon we are into undefined behavior.

If adding those strings is a requirement for your program, then you have to take a step back and re-think the program's text manipulation and buffer strategy, or at least adjust some constants in the program to make things bigger. Maybe it's acceptable for the program to have certain maximum limits and terminate with a diagnostic message if they are exceeded. Or maybe it has to be rewritten to avoid limits (or at least very small, stringent limits), by using dynamic memory allocation.

Some things are impossible. If you ask the helpful clerk at the hardware store about how you can put a 1/4" diameter nut onto a 3/4" diameter bolt, he will probably tell you that it can't be done. This is the programming analog of that.

Answer (score -1):

It is responsibility of programmer to know size of s1. If you don't have enough space you can call realloc(s1,num_of_bytes) to allocate more space.

Comment: No you can't. There's no guarantee that `s1` is dynamic memory in the first place, and even if it was, the caller will never know about the `realloc()`.

Comment: Of course it works only for dynamic allocated space. Before calling strcat programmer have to check for sizes of strings and available space and reallocate s1 if need more.

Comment: If you already know the size of `s1` you should be using `strcpy(&s1[len1], ..` and shouldn't use `strcat()` at all  (so that CPU doesn't need to search through all the chars in `s1` for no reason). If you know the size of both `s1` and `s2` (which you need to know to `realloc()`) then you should be using `memcpy()`.

Comment: Question is about how to handle situation where one use strcat and need more space in destination string. Basically, we have few options:  add space if possible, break code  execution with error status reported to calling function or  simply terminate. If you use other idioms to string concatenation instead of strcat, it is not answer for the question.